# Sacar el contenido de unas columnas (una parte específica) en un texto separado por punto y comas con RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, csv

Tengo un texto algo así:

```
42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion; 8-2º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Lo que intento sacar es lo que está remarcado (`direccion; 8-2º`) con una expresión regular para después poder unificarlo y usar como un texto único y meter dentro de una posición del array.

¿Me podéis echar una mano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para extraer el 5º y 6º campo deberías hacer:

```
^(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]*;[^;]*);
```

Salta los primeros 4 campos separados por `';'` y coge los dos siguientes.

Si lo que quieres es reemplazar el `;` de la dirección por `,` en C#, lo que puedes hacer es meter todo el contenido de la cadena en grupos de captura de forma que puedas utilizarlos en la cadena de reemplazo: un grupo sería todo lo anterior al `';'` que quieres reemplazar, otro el `';'` a reemplazar, y otro el texto a continuación.

Mira este ejemplo con varias líneas:

```cs
string reemplazo =
    @"42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion1; 8-2º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion2, 9-3º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion3; 10-4º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion4, 11-5º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion5; 12-6º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion6, 13-7º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion7; 14-8º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion8; 15-9º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11";

reemplazo = Regex.Replace(reemplazo, "^((?:[^;]*;){4}[^;]*)(;)((?:[^;]*;){27}[^;]*)$", "$1,$3", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.Write(reemplazo);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Si puede haber más de un carácter `';'` en la dirección, se complicaría un poco más:

```cs
string reemplazo =
    @"42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion1; 8-2º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion2, 9-3º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion3; 10-4ºB; 2ºA; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion4, 11-5º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion5; 12-6º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion6, 13-7º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion7; 14-8º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11
    42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion8; 15-9º; SEVILLA;SEVILLA;12345;texto;123456789;;test@gmail.com;123456;;1900-08-20;1904-06-30 00:00:00;0000-00-00 00:00:00;2;1;0000-00-00;0000;1111;1111;11;0123456789;;18;0;0;2;15;ES11";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(reemplazo, "^((?:[^;]*;){4})(.*)((?:;[^;]*){27})$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

var lines = matches.Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{m.Groups[2].Value.Replace(";", ",")}{m.Groups[3].Value}");
reemplazo = string.Join("\r\n", lines);

Console.Write(reemplazo);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Lo que no podría pasar en este caso es que faltaran campos. Si puede haber un número variable de caracteres `';'` en la dirección el número de campos de cada línea tiene que ser el mismo. Si no, no hay forma de saber dónde empieza y dónde acaba la dirección.

Comment: La respuesta es buena, pero necesitaria ignorar los 4 primeros campos y que solo obtenga la parte en negrita. (La expresion es más complicada de lo que esperaba :D)

Comment: ¿Y te devuelve otra cosa? Probando con el texto que has puesto a mí me devuelve "direccion; 8-2º". ¿No es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: Sí, pero a mi me devuelve "42441;27;nombre;apellidos;direccion; 8-2º;" cuando espero solo "direccion; 8-2º;"

Comment: ¿En qué estás programando? Dependiendo del lenguaje pueda haber variaciones, aunque no debería en una tan simple. Puedes comprobar el resultado de la expresión en: https://regex101.com/r/oN2vV0/1

Comment: Es en C# y uso lo siguiente para intentar unificar "direccion; 8-2º" a "direccion, 8-2º":
Match match = Regex.Match(remplazo, "^(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]*;[^;]*);", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 3)
{
remplazo = remplazo.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value, match.Groups[1].Value + ", " + match.Groups[3].Value);
}
Así en la variable "remplazo" me ha de quedar unificado.

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta, pero tengo algunos que ya tienen la dirección completa y por tanto, me une SEVILLA con la dirección. La cadena "reemplazo" contiene la línea de una lectura de un fichero, lo más seguro es que tenga que modificar el fichero en sí, ya que las condiciones varian mucho...

Comment: Pero si lo aplicas a una sola línea te debería funcionar igual

Comment: Por eso es que me gusta tu respuesta. Me sirve pero solo para algunas líneas, pero no para todas. Estoy pensando a ver si puedo poner alguna condición para que sólo me afecte a los que me interese, pero es dificil de definirlo.

Comment: Sí siempre tiene el mismo número de campos sí que se puede. Edito el código para mostrar un ejemplo.

Comment: Perfecto! Me va mucho mejor, aun tengo algunos que tienen la cadena tipo "direccion;4ºB;2ºA;" y solo me hace 1 vez (direccion, 4ºB; 2ºA), pero creo que esos los modifico a mano y ya. Por si acaso, ¿sabes si eso es posible de especificar aun más?

Comment: Sólo con expresiones regulares no se me ocurre. Pero sí tratando un poco el resultado. Edita la respuesta para añadir ese ejemplo.

Comment: He quitado el caso que te fallaba de la respuesta porque entiendo que es más un comentario que parte de la respuesta. El problema en ese caso es que faltan campos por lo que la expresión regular no puede determinar dónde empieza y dónde acaba la dirección. Si puede haber un número variable de caracteres ';' en la dirección y el número de los campos también puede ser variable no hay forma de hacerlo de manera automática.

Comment: Ya lo veo, pero el documento que tengo tiene muchos fallos en los campos. Así que lo revisaré manualmente, gracias por toda tu ayuda.